# how to get cordova plugin installation command?

Tags: cordova, npm, phonegap

I installed many cordova plugins in my project. I am writing documentation and I need to log the exact commands i used to install all plugins.

I can use 'cordova plugins' or 'cordova plugin list' to list installed plugins.
what i want is the exact command that was used to install the plugin. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml. There are your plugins. 
For example:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />`

For install the plugin use command:

`npm install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save`

I hope it'll help

Comment: yes indeed, but is there a way to automatically have this?
i have many plugins installed with several variables in the installation command.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you. `cordova prepare` install all your plugins

Comment: @scatman `i have many plugins installed with several variables in the installation command`. So long as you are using `cordova@7`, then plugin variables will be saved in your `package.json` and `config.xml` so when you run `cordova prepare` on another machine, your plugins (and their variables) will be restored.

Comment: thanks for the hint
when i run cordova prepare, will i see the exact plugin installation commands?
what i want is the exact command i used to install a plugin (some plugin like google and facebook requires additional parameters to be added when installiing the plugin). I also need this information for documentation purposes (not to deploy another environment)